# How remove a single X509 signature?

Tags: c#, .net, pkcs#7

I'm trying to remove just the last signature of a file signed by [SignedCMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms(v=vs.110).aspx).

The function is called [RemoveSignature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysxt16y4(v=vs.110).aspx) and it requires an index, which reflects the signature I need to discard from the signed data.

I didn't find any help in Google about how to utilize it.

I made the following code, where *data* is the signed file in a byte array, which contains **three X509 signatures**:

```
        Dim Contents As New ContentInfo(data)
        Dim signed As New SignedCms(Contents)
        signed.Decode(data)
        signed.RemoveSignature(0)
        dim ResultCode as byte() = signed.ContentInfo.Content
```

The code functions normally (no errors at all) but **always removes all** signatures within the file! Even if I change the index from 0 to 1 or 2, the result is always the file data  **clean of all its signatures**!

Does anyone knows how to remove just the signature pointed by the index of that function (RemoveSignature)?

Thanks for any help!